# A1185 Macbook battery not charging because of low voltage (capacity is still good). Is it dead forever?

Tags: battery

I have an old early-2008 Macbook which I'm using only occasionally (my main machine is now a mid-2012 Macbook Pro).

The old Macbook's battery, since it was a 3rd replacement, still has about 90% capacity. However, I've left it in the Macbook and haven't recharged it for several months now.

Now, when I plug it in, it doesn't charge ("Replace Now"), the light on the charger connector turns green after 2 seconds of orange; and the laptop is powered from the grid. The Battery Health Monitor app (which tells me that the capacity is still ample) tells me that **the voltage of the battery is approximately 7.01 V.**

Is the battery dead forever? Or is there a way to revive it?

(It's Li-Ion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the battery dead forever? Or is there a way to revive it?

The battery is dead and there's no way to revive it.  It's time to replace it with a new one (get a quality battery with an 18 month warranty)

The logic board needs a minimum of 12V to operate.  7V is way under the threshold to turn on and will require the AC adapter to be plugged in.

For further details, see this post:  [Fully charged MacBook Air turns off when power cord removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124839/fully-charged-macbook-air-turns-off-when-power-cord-removed/254180#254180)