# Why my Mac book pro shows status 'Battery is not Charging'?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, battery, charging

I have a MacBook Pro early 2015.Recently I am facing an issue with the battery.
It's not charging.

The MacBook works fine when connected to charger, but it turns off when the charger is removed.

I did a SMC reset, tried another charger too no results. I also tested my charger on another Mac which works just fine.

I took it to the Apple service centre and they said I need to replace the logic board which costs tons of money.

I am confused, do I really need to spend this much money if my laptop just works fine with charger plugged in?

Here is my battery status
[image]

Also status indicator
[image]

Please  suggest me what could be the best solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124839/fully-charged-macbook-air-turns-off-when-power-cord-removed/254180#254180

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is almost EOL with 875 cycle counts.

I would say replace the battery (for about $100 or less)

Comment: Thanks @Buscar. But are you sure that it will solve this issue?

Comment: As said, your Battery is almost End of Life anyway. Battery do have small circuit build in, and yours seems to be kaput. Replacing the battery is not waste of money in your case, you would have to do it in about 125 days anyway. Battery life is 1000 charges, you are at 875.