# Macbook pro “13” mid 2010 battery not holding charge.

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, shutdown

Macbook pro “13” mid 2010 shutdown after removing the megasafe charger. [image: Here is the battery status].

[image: here is the battery information].

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Other possible dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254180/119271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to the images you have provided, your battery is not holding its charge and will need to be replaced.**

In the first image, it says replace now which indicates that it is time for a replacement. In the second image, it also says it is not charging.

> All rechargeable batteries have a limited lifespan and may eventually
>   need to be serviced or recycled. Your own battery’s lifespan will vary
>   depending on how you use your device as well as the settings you
>   choose for it.

Replacement details are avaliable here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/mac/repair/service

The cost depends on what size mac you have and if you have apple care

Comment: Thank you. I quess as much but i just want to be sure before ordering new battery.

Comment: @UpIn No problem! If you found my answer helpful you can feel free to press the tick next to my answer, to let others know that this is the answer if they have a similar issue.