# Apple Macbook SERVICE BATTERY status and where is it stored

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I know for a fact that Service Battery status is stored in macOS files somewhere but not sure where.

Reinstalling Macbook removes this status.
Running Macbook from external OSX removes this status.
Reinstalling OSX and migrating original OSX removes the status.

I'd like to know where is this status hidden in OSX files to remove it without reinstalling??

Does anyone have any idea where to look for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Service Battery" isn't stored in a file somewhere.  It's a value that, for a lack of a better term, is "calculated".  The SMC reads certain values, measures the current charge and depending on the results, you get a "status."

This is why you can have a faulty battery one minute, change it out with a good and it in a few moments, it will give you an updated status of "Charging" or "Charged." (Granted, it takes more than a "minute" to swap a battery, but you get the idea).

You can obtain this information with the [`system_profiler`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254180/119271) command:

```
% system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -i "charge information" -A 10
```

Comment: Thanks!  I reinstalled and migrated same OSX few days ago and status is not coming back.

Answer (score 1):

The OS reads the SMC and caches  the results. I wouldn’t worry so much about altering the filesystem. Just let it run for 15 minutes and open system information to look at the current status is my recommendation.